# Notify TextChanged in an EditText

Tags: android

Is there any way to notify the `EditText` that the text has changed when I do an `EditText.setText("blablabla");`

I have a `SimpleTextChangeListener` attached to this `EditText` and I want this to trigger when I do a `setText` on the `EditText`.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: did you check with text watcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **TextWatcher** to trigger any action on `EditText.setText("blablabla");` If you `setText` to your `EditText`, `onTextChanged()` method will be called. Then you can trigger your desired action there.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                  // Trigger on setText
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fixed, I wasn't calling my ´textOnField()´ method in the ´afterTextChanged()´ for that EditText in particular. Thank you for the help